# JSON Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some issue to retrieve data from JSON, it always said **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**, this is the JSON in the url.php :

```
[{"nama":"IT SERVICE & SOLUTION","nilai":0,"periode":"11","tahun":"2014"},{"nama":"SUBDIV BUSINESS SERVICE","nilai":0,"periode":"11","tahun":"2014"},{"nama":"Data Analytics","nilai":100.1446,"periode":"11","tahun":"2014"}]
```

and this is my code :

```
<?php
$url="url.php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$koyim=  json_decode($json,true);
foreach($koyim as $data){
    echo $data->nilai;
    echo $data->nama;
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

I've been trying different things to retrieve the json but still not having the result, any idea for this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What does `var_dump($koyim)` show?

Comment: it show string() "_jsondata_"

Comment: `url.php` is not returning the JSON that you think.

Comment: I check from http://jsonlint.com/, it is a valid json

Comment: Is it really showing `string() "jsondata"`, or did you mean `string() "[{"nama":...}]"`?

Comment: It's valid JSON, but it's not the JSON for an array, it's the JSON for a string.

Comment: It is possible, there is some problem in from the server that the service gives?

Comment: You did `var_dump($koyim)`, not `var_dump($json)`, right?

Comment: Yes I var_dump($koyim) , and it show string() "[{"nama":...}]", so it is the json string?

Comment: `$json` should be a string, `$koyim` should be an array. It looks like `url.php` encoded the array twice: `echo json_encode(json_encode($array))`.

Comment: You should fix `url.php` so it just encodes once. There's no need for the double encoding.

Answer (score 13):

You need to explicitly turn `json_decode` output to an array. Like this:

```
$koyim = (array)json_decode($json);
```

I had exactly same issue like yours and this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since your JSON is valid, next step is to check for PHP error in decoding.

First try this code to check error while decoding JSON:

```
<?php
    $url="url.php";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $koyim=  json_decode($json,true);

    // Add this switch to your code
    switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
// end of switch

foreach($koyim as $data){
echo $data['nilai'];
echo $data['nama'];
echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Once you know the error you can search for more precise error from CONSTANT in case. Most like its 'JSON_ERROR_UTF8'.

For this you can try this code:
    $url = "url.php";

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($json));

$koyim = json_decode($json,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

i was have this error too, and i have solved it using this:

```php
    $koyim = (array)json_decode($json, true);
```

so, your code should be like this:

```php
    $url = "url.php";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $koyim = (array)json_decode($json, true);
    foreach($koyim as $data) {
        echo $data['nilai'];
        echo $data['nama'];
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the true in the `json_decode()` like this:

```
$koyim=  json_decode($json);
```

Output:

```
0 IT SERVICE & SOLUTION
0 SUBDIV BUSINESS SERVICE
100.1446 Data Analytics
```

Because if you look into the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

And take a quote from there:

> assoc
>   When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: That changes how `{...}` is decoded, but his problem is with `[...]`, which always returns an array.

Comment: Were you getting the `foreach` error before you changed it?

Comment: This change fixes the error he'll get from `$data->nilai`.

Comment: @Rezaakhmadg It works fine for me! Are you sure you changed it?

Comment: @Rizier123 His problem is that the JSON isn't the correct JSON for an array. It's not what he posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the assoc flag that you are setting to `true` when you call `json_decode`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
assoc
When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
```

When assoc flag is set to `true` the returned objects will be converted into associative arrays, with that being said, the way you can access your properties will be using `[]` not `->`

it should work fine using the below code:

```
<?php
$url="url.php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$koyim=  json_decode($json,true);
foreach($koyim as $data){
    echo $data['nilai'];
    echo $data['nama'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This answers a different problem. See my comments to Rizier123's answer.