# ForEach Read Json Get Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, json, foreach

I'm trying to read a json_decode to insert in one MySQL Table but i'm getting this error: *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*, i don't understand why, this is my code:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'myuser', 'mypassword');

$getJsonData = file_get_contents('myurlwiththejsondata');

$data = json_decode($getJsonData);


foreach ($data as $value) {

    $sql = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `ssn`,  `idwork`) VALUES 
        (NULL, :ssn, :idwork) ');

  $sql->bindParam(':ssn', $value->ssn);
  $sql->bindParam(':idwork', $value->idwork);

  $getResult = $sql->execute();
}

$connection = null;
```

But i'm keep getting this warning message: *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*, my data look like this:

```
[
    {"id":"1","ssn":"1000","idwork":"123"}, 
    {"id":"1","ssn":"2000","idwork":"1234"}
]
```

Honestly, i don't understand why my code fails.

Comment: What does it show if you `var_dump($data)` right before your `foreach` statement?

Comment: Cannot recreate if json looks exactly like posted. Please add the `var_dump()` output.

Comment: `string(3521) "[
    {"id":"1","ssn":"1000","idwork":"123"}, 
    {"id":"1","ssn":"2000","idwork":"1234"}...` My var_Dump()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$getJsonData = file_get_contents('myurlwiththejsondata');
// Add this line
$getJsonData = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($getJsonData));
$data = json_decode($getJsonData);
```

If the above code does not work for you than check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37987178/2148519)